# Photoshop Single Row / Column Marquee tools not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I have problems with the Single Row/Column Marquee tools, selections they make disappear the moment I release the mouse button and often, but not always, the cursor changes to (sorry for the picture quality):[image] I reset the tools but it didn't help. "Regular" rectangle and circle marquee tools work as usual. Why is this happening and what should I do to make them work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cursor means that you hover over an existing selection. I would check...:

- if you have `Show Selection Edges` turned on (`View > Show >
  Selection Edges`)
- if your whole canvas is not selected and you're not    adding to an
  existing selection
- if your zoom level is `100%` or more (less than `100%` may cause 1px
  selection edges to be lost due to edges interpolation, especially on
  zoom levels that are not `100/2^x` like `66.7%`, `83.471%`, etc)

Comment: The third option was the case, thanks a lot.